# Upgrade VB 6 projects to Visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008, vb6, vb6-migration

I have a couple of Projects created in visual basic 6 with oracle databases. I want to upgrade these proejects to visual studio 2012 and use TFS version control. I have read that first I need to upgrade to Visual studio 2008 and then to Visual studio 2012.

Before going ahead with the upgrade ( I need to install Visual studio 2008 as well) I want to make sure this is a realistic approach. So
1. Does converting a vb6 project to VS 2012 ok or I will have to make a lot of changes to make things work?
2. After upgradation would I be able to use TFS for the projects?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR - yes, you'll need to make lots of changes regardless of how you choose to migrate. TFS question seems irrelevant to me. If you're setup to use TFS for projects, you can use it for these after upgrade as well.

The only reason to consider a 2-step upgrade that includes VS 2008 is that was the last version that included the migration tool built-in (ie, free). As others alluded to, those tools don't make pretty code but a mashup of VB6 and .Net. After trying a few times, I now personally find it simpler and more robust to recreate a new .Net version from scratch, but using the VB6 code as a template. I copy and paste as practical and then do Find/Replace to catch the majority of errors/warnings and then deal with all the others individually. If I have to convert another project, I may use 2008 once just to see what kind of issues the original code had or if there are any unusual situations/controls I'll need to deal with, but I would still start a new 2013 project from scratch. That gives me a better opportunity to improve it as well. You'd be replacing all the connecting code to Oracle anyway. I'd been using OO4O and moved to ODP.NET. If you used 2008, you would have to move to at least 2010 to use the latter in managed mode, which is great not having to load Oracle Client on each machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be wary of upgrading VB 6 to VB.net using the automated tools. I did it back in the day (around 2003) when .net was just starting out and my memory is that it wasn't a pleasant experience.

The code produced by the upgrade wizard is a nasty mix of old VB conventions `trim`, `instr` and .net conventions. We also had a bunch of weird bugs. Sorry it was a long time ago and I can't remember any details. Only that we did it once for a small number of components, around 6 or 7 activex dll's. That experience was bad enough that we decided it wasn't worth the pain.

We kept the VB 6 code in service until it was re-written as part of a larger push to modernise the codebase.

If you do decide to upgrade then the output is a standard visual studio project that can be source controlled in TFS just like any .net project.

If you reason for upgrading to just to use TFS then take a look at the [MSSCCIProvider](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/06c8e056-7f77-4a5c-9b8b-49318c143df8). This allows you at hook TFS in to the VB6 IDE

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something very similar and did develop a tool to assist with the designer portion of the conversion.  It parsers the VB6 file and creates designer code for .NET.

The source is here.

https://github.com/rdejournett/VBtoNET

The only thing I was not able to solve is that controls within tab pages have really wierd X locations like -60000. So I parse those to 0.  You'll have to move them to the right place.